# CORS problems with Spring Security and Websocket

Tags: spring, security, websocket, cors

I am developing an Ionic app based on a Spring backend.
I implemented Spring Security with JWT authentication. My app will have a chat room where users can talk each other in private or public chat. So, I am implementing a WebSocket system in order to get all updates in real time.

This is my Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

   // configurazione Cors per poter consumare le api restful con richieste ajax
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE"));
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
         httpSecurity
         .csrf().disable()
         .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
         .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
         .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().cors().and()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers(
                 HttpMethod.GET,
                 "/",
                 "/*.html",
                 "/favicon.ico",
                 "/**/*.html",
                 "/**/*.css",
                 "/**/*.js",
                 "/image/**").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/socket/**").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().and()
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and();

         httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

This is my WebSocket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/chat")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/subscribe");
    }
}
```

In this condition, I am currently facing this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:8080/SpringApp/socket/info?t=1547732425329' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Each call is working (i am perfectly authorized with jwt) but the WebSocket can't work.

So, I tried to simply remove the .cors() in configure method in my security configuration class. This lead me to an opposite problem:

[error in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK3Fa.jpg)

Indeed, now WebSocket works perfectly, instead each api call gives me 401.

What's the correct way to resolve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: If you found a solution please post it as an answer. I ran into this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I got the same error when I was working in a related issue in one of my projects. The solution was that I had to set the allowed-origin header value to the URL of my application. The wildcard value (*) is not allowed if you send credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I do that?

Comment: Since you are using the Java configuration of spring security CORS you have to set it in a property file, better in the tomcat configuration (e.g. context.xm of your application) and read that configuration on application startup.

For testing you can set it to localhost, e.g. "http://localhost:8080/"

Comment: Can I do it directly in corsConfigurationSource() method in my WebSecurityConfig class that you can see above?

Comment: Yes, you can set that there. Just replace "*" at addAllowedOrigin() with your application URL